# calculate grand mean from means in r

Tags: r, aggregate

I am trying to aggregate a grand mean from mean scores for students. Here is how my dataset looks like:

```
id <-    c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3, 4,4,4)
mean <- c(5,5,5, 6,6,6, 7,7, 8,8,8)

data <- data.frame(id,mean)

> data
   id mean
1   1     5
2   1     5
3   1     5
4   2     6
5   2     6
6   2     6
7   3     7
8   3     7
9   4     8
10  4     8
11  4     8
```

I am using `dplyr` package for this calculation. I use this,

```
data %>%
  mutate(grand.mean = mean(mean))

   id mean grand.mean
1   1    5   6.454545
2   1    5   6.454545
3   1    5   6.454545
4   2    6   6.454545
5   2    6   6.454545
6   2    6   6.454545
7   3    7   6.454545
8   3    7   6.454545
9   4    8   6.454545
10  4    8   6.454545
11  4    8   6.454545
```

However, this does not consider repeated means for each id. The calculation should be grabbing unique means from each id and average them over. 
so it is `(5+6+7+8)/4 = 6.5` instead of `6.45`.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are duplicates for `mean` in different 'id', use `match` to get the position of the first 'id' and get the `mean` of the 'mean' column

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     mutate(grand.mean = mean(mean[match(unique(id), id)]))
#   id mean grand.mean
#1   1    5        6.5
#2   1    5        6.5
#3   1    5        6.5
#4   2    6        6.5
#5   2    6        6.5
#6   2    6        6.5
#7   3    7        6.5
#8   3    7        6.5
#9   4    8        6.5
#10  4    8        6.5
#11  4    8        6.5
```

---

Or another option is `duplicated`

```
data %>%
       mutate(grand.mean = mean(mean[!duplicated(id)]))
```

---

Or take the `distinct` rows. of 'id', 'mean', get the `mean`, and bind the columns with original dataset

```
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
   distinct(id, mean) %>%
   summarise(grand.mean = mean(mean)) %>% 
   uncount(nrow(data)) %>%
   bind_cols(data, .)
```

Answer (score 3):

A base R one-liner could be:

```
mean(tapply(data$mean, data$id, '[', 1))
#[1] 6.5
```

To put the result in the original data set do

```
data$grand.mean <- mean(tapply(data$mean, data$id, '[', 1))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only need a single answer for the grand mean, just use two 'summarise' steps with 'dplyr':

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(mean)) %>% 
  summarise(grand.mean = mean(mean))
```

Result:

```
  grand.mean
       <dbl>
1        6.5
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unique` and than caluculate `mean` to get a *grand mean*.

```
mean(unique(data)[,"mean"])
#[1] 6.5
```

Or you can aggregate by `id` and then caluculate `mean` to get a *grand mean*.

```
mean(aggregate(mean~id, data, base::mean)[,"mean"])
#[1] 6.5
```

Or use `ave` to get the number repeated values per `id` and use this as a *weight* in `weighted.mean`.

```
weighted.mean(mean, 1/ave(id, id, FUN=length))
#[1] 6.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, we can `group_by` `id` and get the `mean` of `unique` `mean` values in each `id`, then get the `grand_mean` of the entire dataset and do a `right_join` with the original data to add `grand_mean` as a new column.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(grand_mean = mean(unique(mean))) %>%
  mutate(grand_mean = mean(grand_mean)) %>%
  right_join(data, by = 'id')

# A tibble: 11 x 3
#      id grand_mean  mean
#    <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1        6.5     5
# 2     1        6.5     5
# 3     1        6.5     5
# 4     2        6.5     6
# 5     2        6.5     6
# 6     2        6.5     6
# 7     3        6.5     7
# 8     3        6.5     7
# 9     4        6.5     8
#10     4        6.5     8
#11     4        6.5     8
```